# Sending Grid name and class name from XAML button press in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, reflection

I have a WPF program that produces several DataGrids.  I have added capability to export each grid to Excel using the ideas at this site:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/120480/Export-to-Excel-Functionality-in-WPF-DataGrid

Currently I just have a button under each grid that has its own handler that looks something like this:

```
private void m_btnExportTimePartitionToExcel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ExportToExcel<SystemTimeRecordData, List<SystemTimeRecordData>> s = new ExportToExcel<SystemTimeRecordData, List<SystemTimeRecordData>>();
            ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(m_gridPartitionSystemTimeRecords.ItemsSource);
            s.dataToPrint = (List<SystemTimeRecordData>)view.SourceCollection;
            s.GenerateReport();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Problem with exporting Excel. Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I have a similar button handler for each grid.  This all works, but it "smells". It seems there should be a way to have just one handler that each button calls.  That is, if I can pass the grid associated with that button, and the relevant class.  Can I do that from XAML?  I have searched and seen examples of passing arguments, but not the grid itself and certainly not the class, which I'm guessing would have to be passed as a Type?
It would be nice to replace the above code with something like...

```
private void m_btnExportTimePartitionToExcel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
                                    // some how get Type type, and grid from sender and/or e
            ExportToExcel<type, List<type>> s = new ExportToExcel<type, List<type>>();
            ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(m_grid.ItemsSource);
            s.dataToPrint = (List<type>)view.SourceCollection;
            s.GenerateReport();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Problem with exporting Excel. Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Then I could just have one button handler!  Any ideas?
Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Try a Dictionary to map the button name to the DataGrid.  Just cast the Sender to button and access the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few ways you could do that:

- You could try passing the `DataGrid` as the `CommandParameter` if you can find it using an `ElementName` or `RelativeSource` binding

  ```
  <Button CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DataGridA}" ... />

  <!-- Will only work if this is inside the DataGrid somewhere, like in the footer -->
  <Button CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}" ... />
  ```

  You could then get the value with `((Button)sender).CommandParameter as DataGrid`
- You could pass the `ItemsSource` as a `CommandParameter` instead of the entire DataGrid

  ```
  <StackPanel>
      <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}" ... />
      <Button CommandParameter="{Binding SomeCollection}" ... />
  </StackPanel>
  ```
- You could navigate the VisualTree to find the closest DataGrid. I have some [helpers on my blog](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/navigating-wpfs-visual-tree/) that make this easy. Here's an example using them with the above XAML:

  ```
  var parentPanel = VisualTreeHelpers.FindAncestor<StackPanel>((Button)sender);
  var datagrid = VisualTreeHelpers.FindChild<DataGrid>(parentPanel);
  ```

I'm sure there's other ways too, but those are the first ones I thought of :)